# How to cut php-fpm IOPS

Tags: ubuntu, debian, amazon-ec2, php-fpm, iops

I have Amazon EC2 instance with NGINX + PHP-FPM (through socket) + APC.

I see sth. like this in **iotop** on high load.

```
Total DISK READ:       0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE:       0.00 B/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND
 7200 be/4 www-data    0.00 B/s  135.12 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % php-fpm: pool www
 7202 be/4 www-data    0.00 B/s  308.84 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % php-fpm: pool www
 7183 be/4 www-data    0.00 B/s   61.77 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % php-fpm: pool www
 7185 be/4 www-data    0.00 B/s   69.49 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % php-fpm: pool www
 7186 be/4 www-data    0.00 B/s   73.35 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % php-fpm: pool www
 7189 be/4 www-data    0.00 B/s  196.89 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % php-fpm: pool www
 7191 be/4 www-data    0.00 B/s  158.28 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % php-fpm: pool www
```

Most part of logs is disabled already, script doesn't write any files, but there is still lot of disk writes ( up to 500 IOPS according to AWS stats).

Is there any way to reduce disk writes?

Answer (score 1):

You have to figure out why PHP needs to write on disk. In doubt, i'd try to configure PHP sessions to be in a RAM disk.

I still wonder about your iotop output: **Total DISK WRITE: 0.00 B/s**

Comment: I don't use PHP sessions, there is custom code for that and data stored in another place.

"Total DISK WRITE: 0.00 B/s". - weird indeed.